# CLR library dependency path, Java host

Tags: java, .net, dynamic-linking, jni4net

I'm writing a sort of device interface in C# and Java. The C# interfaces with the native device libraries and runs a long living worker thread that polls for data. It does some processing and stores its data in an internal queue.

The Java part starts the worker thread and polls its internal queue. The thread is separate from the main JVM thread.

The trouble is that when I load the C# library, it cannot find the device library dependency. It tries to look in the system dirs and the JVM dir (The Bridge.LoadAndRegisterAssemblyFrom method simply calls the system assembly loader). I resorted the manually opening and loading that dependency from the Java host.

Is there a way to set the CLR library path. I'm not too experienced with .Net, so there might be a generic way, not just for jni4net.